# File path grabber in php or Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, uploadify

my requirement is this :

" When users uploaded one file say "sample.tex" then i need to find the same name PDF file in that directory once he upload the "sample.tex". so file name should be "sample.pdf". we have one form that contain two input file fields.. check the image for reference.

http://img40.imageshack.us/i/proofbb.png/

once user upload the first file and click the "Show Author Email(s)" then i need to find another file "sample.pdf" in the same path and put in below file field. Is that possible in PHP or JQUERY or watever... not only PHP  Even Java is also fine. Please help me to find the solution.

Regards
Dipen

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that with plain JavaScript.  You can't even obtain the path information from your "first file"; all the browser will tell you is the plain file name (that is, the file name without any path information). You also cannot force a "file" input field to be set to a value.

You might be able to do this by creating a signed Java applet, but that's a whole different enchilada and you'd pretty much have to make the whole form be a Java thing.

(There's nothing you can do from PHP, as all the server will get is the plain filename and no path information at all.)

Comment: Thanks bro.. Do you have any Java applet thing related to this. if so please share with me..

Comment: @Dipen sorry, no; it's been over 12 years since I even *thought* about writing a Java applet :-)

Answer (score 0):

Let the user do it. Use [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) with multiple simultaneous uploads enabled. So simple.

Comment: Thanks for your reply buddy.. but my requirement is after upload the one file i need to find out another file automatically based on the name of the first file..USer will choose only one file.. that is the important thing here

Comment: I think it would be a rather large security risk to allow php/javascript to automatically grab a file from your computer without you knowing.